# How to Parse array elements of an url

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have a url which looks like this:

```
http://localhost/projectcode12may2014/ampanel/index.php?rel=common_listing&module=company&field%5B%5D=address&adv_operation%5B%5D=c&value%5B%5D=sector&query_type%5B%5D=AND&submit=Submit
```

In the decoded form, it looks like:

```
http://localhost/projectcode12may2014/ampanel/index.php?rel=common_listing&module=company&field[]=address&adv_operation[]=c&value[]=sector&query_type[]=AND&submit=Submit
```

I am trying to parse this URL and get the values of `field[]`, `adv_operation[]` and `query_type[]` as arrays, but I am just getting `Array` written  in text if I try to parse these fields. I am using `parse_url()` and `parse_str()` for parsing. 
Can anyone suggest a suitable method for this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you have the square brackets in the URI? try to use the keys of key=value& without them.

Comment: Quick question, just to clarify: how are you printing the results of your parsing? (if you're `echo`ing it, it'll always print "Array", since that's what arrays return when casted into a string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably displaying the array section incorrectly, because your method should work.

You use [parse_url](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to extract the "query" segment of the URL, then use [parse_str](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) to load it into a variable.

**Example:**

```
$url = "http://example.com/page.php?a=apple&b=banana&z=zebra&arr[]=1&arr[]=2";
$query = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);

var_dump($query);
// string(40) "a=apple&b=banana&z=zebra&arr[]=1&arr[]=2"

parse_str($query, $parsed);
var_dump($parsed);
/*
array(4) {
  ["a"]=>
  string(5) "apple"
  ["b"]=>
  string(6) "banana"
  ["z"]=>
  string(5) "zebra"
  ["arr"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
}
*/

// $parsed["arr"] is now array(1, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Below are the output formats of the array parameter:

```
$url = '<your_url>';
$parsedUrl = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
parse_str($parsedUrl);

echo $field;
/*
outputs as:
Array
*/

echo $field[0];
/*
outputs as:
address
*/

print_r($field);
/*
outputs as:
Array
(
    [0] => address
)
*/
```